# How check "IsAlive" status of c# async Thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Let's say I have a MyThread class in my Windows C# app like this:

```
public class MyThread
{
   Thread TheThread;

   public MyThread()
   {
      TheThread = new Thread(MyFunc);
   }

   public void StartIfNecessary()
   {
      if (!TheThread.IsAlive)
         TheThread.Start();
   }

   private void MyFunc()
   {
      for (;;)
      {
          if (ThereIsStuffToDo)
             DoSomeStuff();
      }
   }
}
```

That works fine.  But now I realize I can make my thread more efficient by using async/await:

```
public class MyThread
{
   Thread TheThread;

   public MyThread()
   {
      TheThread = new Thread(MyFunc);
   }

   public void StartIfNecessary()
   {
      if (!TheThread.IsAlive)
         TheThread.Start();
   }

   private async void MyFunc()
   {
      for (;;)
      {
         DoSomeStuff();
         await MoreStuffIsReady();
      }
   }
}
```

What I see now, is that the second time I call StartIfNecessary(), TheThread.IsAlive is false (and ThreadState is Stopped BTW) so it calls TheThread.Start() which then throws the ThreadStateException "Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart".  But I can see that DoMoreStuff() is still getting called, so the function is in fact still executing.

I suspect what is happening, is that when my thread hits the "await", the thread I created is stopped, and when the await on MoreStuffIsReady() completes, a thread from the thread pool is assigned to execute DoSomeStuff().  So it is technically true that the thread I created has been stopped, but the function I created that thread to process is still running.

So how can I tell if "MyFunc" is still active?

I can think of 3 ways to solve this:

1) Add a "bool IsRunning" which is set to true right before calling TheThread.Start(), and MyFunc() sets to false when it completes.  This is simple, but requires me to wrap everything in a try/catch/finally which isn't awful but I was hoping there was a way to have the operating system or framework help me out here just in case "MyFunc" dies in some way I wasn't expecting.

2) Find some new function somewhere in System.Threading that will give me the information I need.

3) Rethink the whole thing - since my thread only sticks around for a few milliseconds, is there a way to accomplish this same functionality without creating a thread at all (outside of the thread pool)?  Start "MyFunc" as a Task somehow?

Best practices in this case?

Comment: If you're able to start over, make a [Worker Service](https://medium.com/@nickfane/introduction-to-worker-services-in-net-core-3-0-4bb3fc631225)?

Comment: Oh dear.  Google "async void considered harmful" to get ahead.

Comment: *I can make my thread more efficient by using async/await* <-- In what way the thread becomes more efficient?

Comment: The `MyFunc()` method returns as soon as it hits the `await` statement. That's the end of that thread. See marked duplicate. See also the thousands of related, and in many cases practically identical, questions on Stack Overflow that help explain how async/await works and how you can apply those techniques to your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with a Plain Old Thread and using BlockingCollection to avoid a tight loop:

```
class MyThread
{
    private Thread worker = new Thread(MyFunc);
    private BlockingCollection<Action> stuff = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public MyThread()
    {
        worker.Start();
    }

    void MyFunc()
    {
        foreach (var todo in stuff.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
           try
           {
               todo();
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
              // Something went wrong in todo()
           }
        }
        stuff.Dispose(); // should be disposed!
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
         stuff.CompleteAdding(); // No more adding, but will continue to serve until empty.
    }

    public void Add( Action stuffTodo )
    {
          stuff.Add(stuffTodo); // Will throw after Shutdown is called
    }
}
```

[BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) also shows examples with Task if you prefer to go down that road.

Comment: Usually you would use `GetConsumingEnumerable` instead of doing it the low-level way where you need to manually check if the collection was completed or has any elements. I.e. `foreach (var todo in stuff.GetConsumingEnumerable())` is much simpler than the while-loop, the Take call and the catching of an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Excellent find. Will edit. - Done.

Answer (score 1):

> Rethink the whole thing

This is definitely the best option. Get rid of the thread completely.

It seems like you have a "consumer" kind of scenario, and you need a consumer with a buffer of data items to work on.

One option is to use `ActionBlock<T>` from [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library):

```
public class NeedsADifferentName
{
  ActionBlock<MyDataType> _block;

  public NeedsADifferentName() => _block = new ActionBlock<MyDataType>(MyFunc);

  public void QueueData(MyDataType data) => _block.Post(data);

  private void MyFunc(MyDataType data)
  {
    DoSomeStuff(data);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can build your own pipeline using something like [`Channels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels).